# How can I properly import Blender meshes on keyshot without geometry issues?

Tags: rendering

I can properly visualize this mesh on Blender (fig.1) but seems something goes wrong when importing to keyshot (fig.2).
It is like the boolean cuts get filled with some geometry. What kind of issues is this?
Thank you all[image]

[image]

Comment: This is probably caused by ngons. Try to triangulate the model before export (or in the exporter, if it has such an option).

Comment: Triangulate works perfectly, thank you!